# Increasing Space Between Two Vertical Tables

Tags: tables, spacing, vspace

I'm trying to increase the spacing between the two vertical tables below. However, when I use the `\vspace{5mm}` these tables move with respect to each other.

```
\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccccccc}
& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\\hline 
1& $0.0279\pm 0.0004$ & $0.0279\pm 0.0004$ & $0.0279\pm 0.0004$& $0.0279\pm 0.0004$& $0.0279\pm 0.0004$& $0.0279\pm 0.0004$ \\ 
3& $0.0366\pm 0.0002$ & $0.0366\pm 0.0002$ & $0.0366\pm 0.0002$& $0.0366\pm 0.0002$& $0.0366\pm 0.0002$& $0.0366\pm 0.0002$ \\
6& $0.0386\pm 0.0001$ & $0.0386\pm 0.0001$ & $0.0386\pm 0.0001$& $0.0386\pm 0.0001$& $0.0386\pm 0.0001$& $0.0386\pm 0.0001$ \\
12&$0.0429\pm 0.0001$ & $0.0429\pm 0.0001$ & $0.0429\pm 0.0001$& $0.0429\pm 0.0001$& $0.0429\pm 0.0001$& $0.0429\pm 0.0001$ \\
18&$0.0444\pm 0.0002$ & $0.0444\pm 0.0002$ & $0.0444\pm 0.0002$& $0.0444\pm 0.0002$& $0.0444\pm 0.0002$& $0.0444\pm 0.0002$ \\
24&$0.0459\pm 0.0005$ & $0.0459\pm 0.0005$ & $0.0459\pm 0.0005$& $0.0459\pm 0.0005$& $0.0459\pm 0.0005$& $0.0459\pm 0.0005$ \\
30&$0.0517\pm 0.0009$ & $0.0517\pm 0.0009$ & $0.0517\pm 0.0009$& $0.0517\pm 0.0009$& $0.0517\pm 0.0009$& $0.0517\pm 0.0009$ \\
36&$0.0524\pm 0.0007$ & $0.0524\pm 0.0007$ & $0.0524\pm 0.0007$& $0.0524\pm 0.0007$& $0.0524\pm 0.0007$& $0.0524\pm 0.0007$ \\
48&$0.0553\pm 0.0017$ & $0.0553\pm 0.0017$ & $0.0553\pm 0.0017$& $0.0553\pm 0.0017$& $0.0553\pm 0.0017$& $0.0553\pm 0.0017$ \\
60&$0.0564\pm 0.0014$ & $0.0564\pm 0.0014$ & $0.0564\pm 0.0014$& $0.0564\pm 0.0014$& $0.0564\pm 0.0014$& $0.0564\pm 0.0014$ \\
72&$0.0683\pm 0.0046$ & $0.0683\pm 0.0046$ & $0.0683\pm 0.0046$& $0.0683\pm 0.0046$& $0.0683\pm 0.0046$& $0.0683\pm 0.0046$ \\ \hline  \hline 
72&$0.0683\pm 0.0046$ & $0.0683\pm 0.0046$ & $0.0683\pm 0.0046$& $0.0683\pm 0.0046$& $0.0683\pm 0.0046$& $0.0683\pm 0.0046$ \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\newline
\vspace{5mm}
\newline
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccccccc}
& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\\hline
1& $0.0279\pm 0.0004$ & $0.0279\pm 0.0004$ & $0.0279\pm 0.0004$& $0.0279\pm 0.0004$& $0.0279\pm 0.0004$& $0.0279\pm 0.0004$ \\ 
3& $0.0366\pm 0.0002$ & $0.0366\pm 0.0002$ & $0.0366\pm 0.0002$& $0.0366\pm 0.0002$& $0.0366\pm 0.0002$& $0.0366\pm 0.0002$ \\
6& $0.0386\pm 0.0001$ & $0.0386\pm 0.0001$ & $0.0386\pm 0.0001$& $0.0386\pm 0.0001$& $0.0386\pm 0.0001$& $0.0386\pm 0.0001$ \\
12&$0.0429\pm 0.0001$ & $0.0429\pm 0.0001$ & $0.0429\pm 0.0001$& $0.0429\pm 0.0001$& $0.0429\pm 0.0001$& $0.0429\pm 0.0001$ \\
18&$0.0444\pm 0.0002$ & $0.0444\pm 0.0002$ & $0.0444\pm 0.0002$& $0.0444\pm 0.0002$& $0.0444\pm 0.0002$& $0.0444\pm 0.0002$ \\
24&$0.0459\pm 0.0005$ & $0.0459\pm 0.0005$ & $0.0459\pm 0.0005$& $0.0459\pm 0.0005$& $0.0459\pm 0.0005$& $0.0459\pm 0.0005$ \\
30&$0.0517\pm 0.0009$ & $0.0517\pm 0.0009$ & $0.0517\pm 0.0009$& $0.0517\pm 0.0009$& $0.0517\pm 0.0009$& $0.0517\pm 0.0009$ \\
36&$0.0524\pm 0.0007$ & $0.0524\pm 0.0007$ & $0.0524\pm 0.0007$& $0.0524\pm 0.0007$& $0.0524\pm 0.0007$& $0.0524\pm 0.0007$ \\
48&$0.0553\pm 0.0017$ & $0.0553\pm 0.0017$ & $0.0553\pm 0.0017$& $0.0553\pm 0.0017$& $0.0553\pm 0.0017$& $0.0553\pm 0.0017$ \\
60&$0.0564\pm 0.0014$ & $0.0564\pm 0.0014$ & $0.0564\pm 0.0014$& $0.0564\pm 0.0014$& $0.0564\pm 0.0014$& $0.0564\pm 0.0014$ \\
72&$0.0683\pm 0.0046$ & $0.0683\pm 0.0046$ & $0.0683\pm 0.0046$& $0.0683\pm 0.0046$& $0.0683\pm 0.0046$& $0.0683\pm 0.0046$ \\ \hline  \hline
72&$0.0683\pm 0.0046$ & $0.0683\pm 0.0046$ & $0.0683\pm 0.0046$& $0.0683\pm 0.0046$& $0.0683\pm 0.0046$& $0.0683\pm 0.0046$ \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
```

Comment: remove both the `\newline` and put a blank line before `\vspace` (also please always post a complete small document not just a fragment, so people can run the code and see the issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove both the `\newline` and put a blank line before `\vspace`

`tabular` are positioned by exactly the same logic as letters, and here you want two centred paragraphs.